# Paging library is not sending any data to my PagedListAdapter

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging

I have an Android To-do list app with SQLite database accessed using Room. Then I wanted to make a list of available lists in navigation drawer. So I used Paging Library. Now the RecyclerView is empty and I don't know why. BTW: none of my lists work. I am a beginner, so I stick to the official tutorial. I've already found out, that they are wrong and that `ViewModel` needs an empty constructor. Now the situation looks like this: the method, that sets up the adapter is called successfully (8), `ViewModel` is created (7) `Adapter` is created (1), the `setList()` method is called (9), but no `Holder` is being created (4), no `onCreateViewHolder` or `onBindViewHolder` are called (2,3), no `DiffCalback` methods are called (5,6) and just an empty Recycler view is displayed. The `PagedList<SQLList>` contains right information, but no information is being passed to the adapter. Has anybody any idea why?
//Sorry for my English.

Adapter class:

```
//this is my Adapter. SQLList is my object (Equivalent to the User object in 
the tutorial)
public class ListsAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<SQLList,ListsAdapter.Holder> {
private Context context;

public ListsAdapter(Context context) {
//1
    super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //2
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
    return new Holder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
    //3
    SQLList item = getItem(position);
    if (item == null){
        holder.clear();
    }else {
        holder.bindTo(item);
    }
}




public static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public int id;
    public TextView idView;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        //4
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        idView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
    }

    public void bindTo(SQLList list) {
        textView.setText(list.getName());
        id = list.getId();
        idView.setText(Integer.toString(list.getId()));
    }

    public void clear() {
        textView.setText("");
        id = 0;
        idView.setText("0");
    }
}

private static final DiffCallback<SQLList> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffCallback<SQLList>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull SQLList oldItem, @NonNull SQLList newItem) {
        //5
        return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull SQLList oldItem, @NonNull SQLList newItem) {
        //6
        return oldItem.getName().equals(newItem.getName());
    }
};
}
```

View Model:

```
public static class ListViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public final LiveData<PagedList<SQLList>> listsList;
    public ListViewModel(){
        //7
        listsList = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(DMO.getDao().loadListFactory(),20).build();
    }
}
```

Part of Fragment the `RecyclerView` is placed in:

```
 ...
 //8
 ListViewModel listViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListViewModel.class);
    adapter = new ListsAdapter(context);
    listViewModel.listsList.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<SQLList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<SQLList> sqlLists) {
          //9  
          adapter.setList(sqlLists);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
...
```

Comment: @pskink the list is successfully passed to the `PagedListAdapterHelper` and `getItemCount()` returns the right value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Problem found: I forgot to set layout manager!

Comment: Same here :)    Thanks ...

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem but I accidentally added-

```
RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

After removing this, It worked.

Comment: You're a Life saver!

Comment: Spent almost one month to understand that, thank you is finally working erasing this line

Answer (score 4):

Same issue I had and I just removed RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true) then it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had to set the adapter. `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: It's there in the code. Good point anyway, someone might forgot.